TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str. Using record_path
I've recently encountered a problem and can't seem to solve it. In my project I need to set the index of my pandas dataframe to a variable found in a Json file. The JSON file i'm using looks like this:
{
"data": {
    "events": [
        {
            "id": "3745060",
            "externalIds": [
                {
                    "id": "10244973",
                    "provider": "betgenius"
                },
                {
                    "id": "sr:match:41888589",
                    "provider": "betradar"
                }
            ],
            "extKey": null,
            "retailCode": null,
            "name": "Norwich City FC v Ipswich Town",

From this file I need to extract the variable 'name'. In an attempt to use this I used the following lines of code:
api = 'https://content.toto.nl/content-service/api/v1/q/event-list?startTimeFrom=2024-04-05T22%3A00%3A00Z&started=false&maxMarkets=10&orderMarketsBy=displayOrder&marketSortsIncluded=--%2CCS%2CDC%2CDN%2CHH%2CHL%2CMH%2CMR%2CWH&marketGroupTypesIncluded=CUSTOM_GROUP%2CDOUBLE_CHANCE%2CDRAW_NO_BET%2CMATCH_RESULT%2CMATCH_WINNER%2CMONEYLINE%2CROLLING_SPREAD%2CROLLING_TOTAL%2CSTATIC_SPREAD%2CSTATIC_TOTAL&eventSortsIncluded=MTCH&includeChildMarkets=true&prioritisePrimaryMarkets=true&includeCommentary=true&includeMedia=true&drilldownTagIds=691&excludeDrilldownTagIds=7291%2C7294%2C7300%2C7303%2C7306'
re = r.get(api)
red = re.json()

df = pd.json_normalize(red, record_path=['data', 'events'], meta=[['data', 'events', 'markets', 'outcomes', 'type'], ['data', 'events', 'markets', 'outcomes', 'subType'], ['data', 'events', 'name']])
#meta_col = 'data.events.markets.outcomes.type'
#meta_thuis = 'data.events.markets.outcomes.subType'
game = df['name']
print(game)

I've used similar code for different JSON files and different variables and have never encountered this problem. No idea what's the next step in solving this so definitely could use some help <3

pd.json_normalize() returns a dataframe, you can't get this error from the code you posted. There must be more to it.

I think you need to first access the 'name' variable inside each event object in the 'events' list. Then, you can set it as the index of your DataFrame.

Please post a [mre]. The API call is irrelevant, just post some sample literal data.

Also it seems like you are trying to extract the 'name' variable from the 'events' list in your JSON file and set it as the index of your pandas DataFrame.

Removing the meta within the json_normalize seems to solve the problem, but I need the meta to access other variables within the JSON so removing it is (as far as I now) not really an option.

@Barmar, i've put in the entirety of the code and the api

The error is happening within json_normalize(), I had assumed it was from df['name']. That's why you should post the full traceback.

@nijhof.ngsvn look at the last part of my answer, I think this is what you're looking for.

Is this what you're looking for?
import pandas as pd
import requests

api = 'https://content.toto.nl/content-service/api/v1/q/event-list?startTimeFrom=2024-04-05T22%3A00%3A00Z&started=false&maxMarkets=10&orderMarketsBy=displayOrder&marketSortsIncluded=--%2CCS%2CDC%2CDN%2CHH%2CHL%2CMH%2CMR%2CWH&marketGroupTypesIncluded=CUSTOM_GROUP%2CDOUBLE_CHANCE%2CDRAW_NO_BET%2CMATCH_RESULT%2CMATCH_WINNER%2CMONEYLINE%2CROLLING_SPREAD%2CROLLING_TOTAL%2CSTATIC_SPREAD%2CSTATIC_TOTAL&eventSortsIncluded=MTCH&includeChildMarkets=true&prioritisePrimaryMarkets=true&includeCommentary=true&includeMedia=true&drilldownTagIds=691&excludeDrilldownTagIds=7291%2C7294%2C7300%2C7303%2C7306'

res = requests.get(api).json()

df = pd.DataFrame({'name': map(lambda x: x['name'], res['data']['events'])})
display(df)

The result:
    name
0   Norwich City FC v Ipswich Town
1   Blackburn Rovers v Southampton FC
2   Cardiff City v Hull City
3   Coventry City v Leeds United
4   Huddersfield Town v Millwall
5   Leicester City v Birmingham City
6   Middlesbrough v Swansea City
7   Queens Park Rangers v Sheffield Wednesday
8   Stoke City v West Bromwich Albion
9   Sunderland AFC v Bristol City
10  Watford v Preston North End

The issue in your code is because 'events' isn't an object but a list, so you can't reach 'markets' by the key in meta parameter.
Another thing you can do is use flatten_json, like this:
pip install flatten_json

from flatten_json import flatten
   
data = res['data']['events']
dict_flattened = (flatten(d, '.') for d in data)
df = pd.DataFrame(dict_flattened)

By doing this, you can get df['name'] but also some columns like this:
display(df['markets.0.outcomes.0.type'])

Now, if you want the markets outcomes with the game's name, then you can do this:
df = pd.json_normalize(res['data']['events'], ['markets', ['outcomes']], ['name'], meta_prefix='game_')

The result with the game name in the 'game_name' column would look like this:

Finally, if you want the game_name column to become the index of your dataframe, simply group by the game_name column and set agg to others relevant columns.
